# process url from rss feed as new items come in

Tags: c#, .net

Can someone recommend an appropriate way to do this.

I'm subscribed to a number of rss feeds. What I would like to do is 
obtain the url and then do  DoSomething(url) when i have the url of the new item that has come in.

basically process the new item as it comes in.

What would I need to do to have this automatically? without me having to force the process?

Comment: What are you using to get the RSS feeds, are you using the `System.ServiceModel.Syndication` classes?

Comment: I haven't coded anything yet - i just need a rough idea on how to approacah this

Comment: Probably want to look at using .NET Syndication to subscribe to feeds and received articles.  You could check the Unique Id of each article and if it's new, add it to an `ObservableCollection` of articles.  If you hook up to the events on the `ObservableCollection` your app can then act automatically when new articles arrive with no need for intervention.  You can get URL content using the WebRequest class and run the whole thing as a Windows Service.  You could save the state of the app and articles as an XML file or into a database.  Plenty to look into there anyway to get you started :-)

Answer (score 1):

Make scheduler to send request to RSS feed source once per munute/hour/other time period.

Parse responce via stuff from `System.ServiceModel.Syndication` namespace - you'll have a collection of `SyndicationItems` that represents obtained data.

For each item that you don't have in your storage - run DoSomething with url from `SyndicationItem.Links`.